# Symfony Doctrine querybuilder, make and sorting my request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, request

### I have 3 entities:

1 : vehicule
2 : users
3 : bags

### Relations are simple

users > ManyToOne > vehicule
bags > ManyToOne > vehicule

I want to return a list of vehicles, with a count on the number of users and a count on the number of bags, sorted by the number of users. A classic request, but I dont succeed.

Here is my no working code witch sent me my list but not the correct number of users and bags.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('v.id, v.name')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(b.id) as nbbags,COUNT(u.id) as nbusers')
        ->leftJoin('c.Users', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('c.Bags', 'b')
        ->setMaxResults(150)
        ->orderBy('nbusers', 'desc')
        ->addOrderBy('nbbags')
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->getQuery();
    return $qb->execute();
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: show the entity code. Probably you can do this without joins. select the entities you need, then as you loop through the list do something like `$vehicle->getBags()->count();`

Comment: Yes I know this approach but I really want to sort it directly in the SQL request

Comment: try `->addSelect('COUNT(b) as nbbags,COUNT(u) as nbusers')`

Comment: Nope, already try, it sounds simple but it's complicated right?